# How do I output the DNN Page's "Large Icon" in 2sxc?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm making a Hero app using 2sxc. On the DNN site I'm working on, the administrator set the "Large Icon" via the page settings to have a banner image. I would like to grab this banner image and use it within the 2sxc app.

I thought I might be able to use @CmsContext.Page.LargeIcon but that renders an error:

"error CS1061: 'ToSic.Sxc.Context.ICmsPage' does not contain a definition for 'LargeIcon' and no extension method 'LargeIcon' accepting a first argument of type 'ToSic.Sxc.Context.ICmsPage' could be found"

Is it possible to grab the page's Large Icon for display within a 2sxc app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have (Accuraty has) a few utility functions that help us get at this stuff (when 2sxc doesn't make it easy in .Razor12+). In general, you can do it on the fly with something like:

```
var pageTabInfo = DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.Instance.GetTab(PageId, SiteId);
```

This returns a TabInfo object so then just:

```
@pageTabInfo.IconFileLarge
```

If you want a working function you can reuse:

```
@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor14
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals // PortalSettings
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs // TabInfo

@functions {
  public TabInfo GetPage(int pageId, int siteId = -1)
  {
    if (siteId == -1)
    {
      siteId = PortalSettings.Current.PortalId;
    }
    return TabController.Instance.GetTab(pageId, siteId);
  }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
<p>Page (TabInfo) .IconFileLarge = @GetPage(CmsContext.Page.Id).IconFileLarge</p>
```

---

Note: if you are using 2sxc v16.03 or higher, e.g.

`@inherits Custom.Hybrid.RazorTyped`,

Then instead of `CmsContext.Page...`, you would use `MyPage...`

```
<p>Page (TabInfo) .IconFileLarge = @GetPage(MyPage.Id).IconFileLarge</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error:

"Hero\Hero.cshtml(6): error CS0103: The name 'PageId' does not exist in the current context at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()"

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it wasn't supposed to be working code. You need to pass in the PageId (TabID). So if you are using modern 2sxc .Razor12 or .Razo14 then pass in `CmsContext.Page.Id` for the current page. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ended up using @GetPage(@CmsContext.Page.Id).IconFileLarge

Comment: great. BTW: the second `@` is wrong, better just `@GetPage(CmsContext.Page.Id).IconFileLarge`

Comment: @iJungleBoy - I did come back and edit/fix the code above.